# Lista desplegable con valores predeterminados

Tags: javascript, lista

quiero tener una opcion en una web, la cual al presionar un boton, me genero una lista desplegable con valores predeterminados, pero no se como; ya intente con select y option pero no logro crear las opciones

```js
var caja = document.getElementById("caja");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function (){
 var lista  = document.createElement("Select");
   lista.setAttribute("type", "option");
   lista.setAttribute("value", "dasd");
   caja.appendChild(lista);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lagranestafa.css">
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>   
   <br>
   <input type="button" name="" id="btn">

    <br>
  
   <div id="caja"></div>

 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="eje2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los option de un select son también elementos de JS, por lo que tienes que crearlos con "createElement" y añadirlos como hijos al elemento "select".

Prueba esto

```
var select = document.createElement( 'select' );

//Opción A
var optionA = document.createElement( 'option' );
optionA.value = 'optA'; //Valor que te llegará en el formulario
optionA.textContent = 'Opción A'; // Texto visible.
select.appendChild(optionA);

var optionB = document.createElement( 'option' );
optionB.value = 'optB';
optionB.textContent = 'Opción B';
select.appendChild(optionB);
```